# What commercially-available platforms similar to OpenCalais or AlchemyAPI are there for entity extraction for Chinese and Japanese languages?

Tags: entity, nlp, semantics, freebase, opencalais

In particular, I would like to be able to extract people, places, films, music, etc. entities and have the entities available in widely used linked data IDs such as DBpedia, Freebase, or OpenCyc.

Answer (score 2):

[Extractiv](http://extractiv.com) is a similar service which combines a web crawler from [80legs](http://80legs.com) with natural language processing from [Language Computer Corporation](http://languagecomputer.com) (LCC). This service currently provides more than 150 entity types, such as the ones you list, and [links them](http://blog.extractiv.com/blog/2010/11/12/semantic-on-demand-adds-entity-linking-with-dbpedia-support.html) to DBpedia.

While not yet deployed to Extractiv as web service, LCC's [CiceroLite](http://www.languagecomputer.com/products/text-annotation/cicerolite.html) named entity tagger supports both Chinese and Japanese.  This can be purchased as a standalone application.  Another such company would be [Basis Technology](http://www.basistech.com/entity-extraction/), although I do not know that these entities are linked.